# How to set javascript localize for calculate float with virgule?

Tags: javascript

In my system, I need consider numbers like `1,50` for float and `1.50` for string

I had searched in Google some ways, like apply replace

```
value = value.replace(\,\g, '.');
value = parseFloat(value);
```

But this way, is allowing calculate if user type `1.50` in value, I need add any rules for handler this problem.

Maybe is not consistent.

So, has anyway to set browser localize to consider `1,50` is float and `1.50` not? This is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method. You need to check whether or not the given value is a valid Javascript number. Then you can reject this value.

```
//attemp to convert value to number
//if string is 1,50 it outputs NaN
if(isNaN(Number(value))){
   var value = Number(value.replace(\,\g, '.'));
}else{ 
   alert('Invalid number');
}
```